# Changing STDOUT to file in ncat source code

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I managed to compile ncat. I am using -k option to keep server open. Instead of accepting data to STDOUT, my goal is to write to files instead. So far I was able to write to a file instead of STDOUT but my goal is to loop through new files on each new connection. Right now it is appending to the same filename_0 and f++ is not incrementing. Here is what I have so far. The original code will be below. The difference is in the else clause, basically if n is actually greater than 0. On each loop, n is 512 bytes until the last chunk. I just want to be able to have new files from each new connection. filename_0, filename_1, filename_3, etc.

MODIFIED CODE:

```
/* Read from a client socket and write to stdout. Return the number of bytes
   read from the socket, or -1 on error. */
int read_socket(int recv_fd)
{
    char buf[DEFAULT_TCP_BUF_LEN];
    struct fdinfo *fdn;
    int nbytes, pending;
    int f = 0;    

    fdn = get_fdinfo(&client_fdlist, recv_fd);
    ncat_assert(fdn != NULL);
    nbytes = 0;
    do {
        int n, s;
  
        n = ncat_recv(fdn, buf, 512, &pending);
        
        if (n <= 0) {
            if (o.debug)
                logdebug("Closing fd %d.\n", recv_fd);
#ifdef HAVE_OPENSSL
            if (o.ssl && fdn->ssl) {
                if (nbytes == 0)
                    SSL_shutdown(fdn->ssl);
                SSL_free(fdn->ssl);
            }
#endif
            close(recv_fd);
            checked_fd_clr(recv_fd, &master_readfds);
            rm_fd(&client_fdlist, recv_fd);
            checked_fd_clr(recv_fd, &master_broadcastfds);
            rm_fd(&broadcast_fdlist, recv_fd);

            conn_inc--;
            if (get_conn_count() == 0)
                checked_fd_clr(STDIN_FILENO, &master_readfds);

            return n;
        }
        else {
            char filename[20];
            snprintf(filename, sizeof(char) * 20, "filename_%i", f);
            FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "a");
            if (fp == NULL)
            {
                printf("Could not open file");
                return 0;
            }
            //Write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
            s = fwrite(buf, 1, n, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            f++;
            nbytes += n;
        }

    } while (pending);

    return nbytes;
}
```

ORIGINAL CODE:

```
int read_socket(int recv_fd)
{
    char buf[DEFAULT_TCP_BUF_LEN];
    struct fdinfo *fdn;
    int nbytes, pending;

    fdn = get_fdinfo(&client_fdlist, recv_fd);
    ncat_assert(fdn != NULL);

    nbytes = 0;
    do {
        int n;

        n = ncat_recv(fdn, buf, sizeof(buf), &pending);
        if (n <= 0) {
            if (o.debug)
                logdebug("Closing fd %d.\n", recv_fd);
#ifdef HAVE_OPENSSL
            if (o.ssl && fdn->ssl) {
                if (nbytes == 0)
                    SSL_shutdown(fdn->ssl);
                SSL_free(fdn->ssl);
            }
#endif
            close(recv_fd);
            checked_fd_clr(recv_fd, &master_readfds);
            rm_fd(&client_fdlist, recv_fd);
            checked_fd_clr(recv_fd, &master_broadcastfds);
            rm_fd(&broadcast_fdlist, recv_fd);

            conn_inc--;
            if (get_conn_count() == 0)
                checked_fd_clr(STDIN_FILENO, &master_readfds);

            return n;
        }
        else {
            Write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
            nbytes += n;
        }
    } while (pending);

    return nbytes;
}
```

Comment: You’re setting the variable to zero every time. You’ll need to use a global or a static variable instead.

Comment: i did try putting static f = 0 inside the loop or outside and all that ends up happening is it creates a million files of filename_0, filename_1, each of 512 bytes

Comment: also if thats the case i also notice they set nbytes to 0 again as well. i dont understand why the function should return nbytes if its always set to 0? the whole point of nbytes is to keep track of how many bytes were passed from n, so i dont understand their logic there either

Comment: That’s to be expected since you create files inside the loop. This seems to be the inner loop for a single connection. You should open a file in the beginning, write things in, close in the end. The logic seems quite simple. It returns the amount of bytes since it’s updated. It’s zero *in the beginning for each connection*, as it should.

Comment: How do I have all the bytes go into one file for each connection? That's the problem I am having, not sure how to set that up. Is it supposed to be handled outside this function, from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out using the other functions involved. i passed a pointer into this function to write to it. the handler is a function i added the open() file pointer to.